# DirectSumMat for general fields in GAP

Tags: gap

The GAP-command DirectSumMat allows to take the direct sum of matrices over (only certain?) fields.
Now I did the following in GAP:

```
F:=FunctionField(Rationals,["x1","x2","x3","x4"]);AssignGeneratorVariables(F);
N:=[[x1,x2],[x3,x4]];U:=DirectSumMat(N,N);
```

This gives an error so it seems that the command DirectSumMat does not work over the field F:=FunctionField(Rationals,["x1","x2","x3","x4"]); or am I using the command wrong?
The command DirectSumMat seems to work fine over the rationals.

> Question: Is there an easy fix for this so that one can take the direct sum of matrices over any fields in GAP?

Comment: Hi Mare, I would recommend for future questions that you also state the version of GAP you are using, and include the full input and output of your GAP session, to make it easier to understand what's going on. In this case, your code works in GAP up to 4.11.1, and is broken in 4.12.0 onwards -- i.e., there is a bug. I'll file this in the GAP issue tracker.

Comment: @MaxHorn Thank you. Ill look up the version the next time I use my laptop again that I used when asking this question. Is there a way to see whehter the code for DirectSumMat and see how it was changed during those versions? Maybe I can see the code and modify it.

Comment: It is not the code for `DirectSumMat` that changed but the mechanism for determining a base field from the matrix entries.

Comment: @hulpe actually the code for `DirectSumMat` did change quite a lot. of course the core which does the actual work did not

Comment: See https://github.com/gap-system/gap/issues/5434

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround until `DirectSumMat` is fixed (hopefully in GAP 4.13.0, to be released in a couple weeks if all goes well), you can use this helper. For simplicity, it takes the coefficient ring plus two matrices; if you need more you can either call it multiple times or adapt it suitably):

```
MyDirectSumMat:=function(R,m1,m2)
  local m, r1, r2, c1, c2;
  r1 := NrRows(m1);
  r2 := NrRows(m2);
  c1 := NrCols(m1);
  c2 := NrCols(m2);
  m := NullMat(r1+r2, c1+c2, R);
  CopySubMatrix(m1, m, [1..r1], [1..r1], [1..c1], [1..c1] );
  CopySubMatrix(m2, m, [1..r2], [r1+1..r1+r2], [1..c2], [c1+1..c1+c2] );
  return m;
end;
```

Example:

```
gap> F:=FunctionField(Rationals,["x1","x2","x3","x4"]);AssignGeneratorVariables(F);
FunctionField(...,[ x1, x2, x3, x4 ])
#I  Assigned the global variables [ x1, x2, x3, x4 ]
gap> N:=[[x1,x2],[x3,x4]];
[ [ x1, x2 ], [ x3, x4 ] ]
gap> U:=MyDirectSumMat(F, N, N);
[ [ x1, x2, 0, 0 ], [ x3, x4, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, x1, x2 ], [ 0, 0, x3, x4 ] ]
```